# ZF2 Doctrine2 Form validation NoObjectExists

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm using \DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists to validate my form submission. But, like the ZendDB adapter, I need to exclude all the rows where FieldX equals to SomethingX.

How can I achive that?

This is my form, filter input:

```
$filter->add(
        $factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'example',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => '\DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'object_repository' => $this->mainRepository,
                        'fields' => 'example'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ))
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Going by the Source-Code it appears you'd need to write your own Validator to do this.

Comment: Yes, this is a very particular use case. Your own validator would perform better here.

Comment: Did you find any way to fix this issue.